# How to set include directory per project in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake that generate several projects for visual studio. I have a line in cmake that sets include directory as follow:

```
include_directories(
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${LIBLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${LIBE57_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CERES_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${NANOFLANN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
     )
```

Bit it sets this for all projects, is there anyway that I set it per project? So project A only have access to Boost include dir and project B only has Opencv include dir for example?

I found this post that says it would be implemented later in 2011:

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-April/028682.html

Comment: Have you tried reading [the CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/documentation/) for your version of CMake?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg which part? I could not find any solution there :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `target_include_directories`

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html